# Get data from Datagridview and put in dictionary c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, data-dictionary

I have a datagridview contains 2 columns. "Email" and "Amount".
I just want to get data from these two columns and put in data-dictionary, EMAIL as Key and the AMOUNT as Value.
How could i get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dictionary<String, Int32> myDic = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myDGV.Rows)
{
    String mail = row.Cells["Mail"].Value;
    Int32 amount = row.Cells["Amount"].Value;

    if (myDict.ContainsKey(mail))
        myDic[mail] += amount;
    else
        myDic.Add(mail, amount);
}
```

You can also use an indexed approach where `0` is the index of your `Mail` column and `1` is the index of your `Amount` column:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myDGV.Rows)
{
    String mail = row.Cells[0].Value;
    Int32 amount = row.Cells[1].Value;

    if (myDict.ContainsKey(mail))
        myDic[mail] += amount;
    else
        myDic.Add(mail, amount);
}
```

If your `DataGridView` contains rows with the same mail, my code handles this case by incrementing the respective `Dictionary` value.